# Spivak Chapter 11 Appendix Problem 10b

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have solved part A, but I am failing to make any progress at all for part b. Can someone at least lead me in a direction? This problem is very difficult to visualize intuitively (for me), and I'm not sure how I would even go about solving it.

> (a) For any function $f$, the right-hand derivative $\lim_{h\to0+}[f(a+h)-f(a)]/h$, is denoted by $f'_+(a)$, and the left-hand derivative is denoted by $f'_-(a)$. The proof of Theorem 1 actually shows that $f'_+$ and $f'_-$ always exist if $f$ is convex. Check this assertion, and also show that $f'_+$ and $f'_-$ are increasing, and that $f'_-(a)\leq f'_+(a)$.
>
> (b) Show that if $f$ is convex, then $f'_+(a)=f'_-(a)$ if and only if $f'_+$ is continuous at $a$. (Thus $f$ is differentiable precisely when $f'_+$ is continuous.) Hint: $[f(b)-f(a)](b-a)$ is close to $f'_(a)$ for $b<a$ close to $a$, and $f'_+(b)$ is less than this quotient.

Here's my progress to part (a) here, since amWhy requested it:

Consider $f_+'$. Note that because $f$ is convex, considering $h>0$, we have that $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is decreasing. Not only so, it is bounded by $\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{h}$ for any positive $h$. A decreasing sequence with a lower bound, therefore, has a limit. The proof for f- is similar.

Next, to show that $f_+'$ is increasing, we'll consider 2 points $a, b$. Note that $f_+'(a)<\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ (use the limit definition if you'd like), and that $f_-'(b)>\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. Therefore, $f_+'(a)<f_-'(b)$.

Now, we'll show that $f_-'(a) \le f_+'(a)$. To do this, note that any $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is larger than $\frac{f(a-h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Finally, $f_-'(a) \le f_+'(a) < f_-'(b) \le f_+'(b)$, which shows that $f_+$ and $f_-$ are increasing.

Comment: This is standard stuff, check out books on Convex Analysis: Rockafellar, Boyd-Vandenberghe and many others.

Comment: I'm not studying convex analysis, but rather calculus...

Comment: Fair enough. I suggest you google Boyd-Vandenberghe's convex optimization book, which is available for free. It should be in there.

Comment: I think Spivak would prefer readers asking rather than spending time to read another book in case of doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Spivak's suggestion:

You should have proven in part (a) that if $b<a<c$, then
$$\tag1
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\leq f'_-(a)\leq f'_+(a)\leq \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}
$$

Suppose that $f'_-(a)=f'_+(a)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0\leq a-b<\delta$, then
$$\tag2
0\leq f'_-(a)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<\varepsilon.
$$
Similarly, if $0<b-a<\delta$, 
$$\tag3
0\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'_+(a)<\varepsilon.
$$
Thus, if $0<b-a<\delta$, we get from $(3)$ that 
$$
0\leq f'_+(b)-f'_+(a)\leq\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'_+(a)<\varepsilon.
$$
This shows that $f'_+$ is right continuous, which doesn't require the hypothesis.

Now if
if $0<a-b<\delta$, using $(2)$ we get 
$$
0\leq f'_+(a)-f'_+(b)=f'_-(a)-f'_+(b)<\varepsilon+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'_+(b)\leq\varepsilon. 
$$
So $f'_+$ is also right-continuous at $a$, and so it is continuous at $a$.

Conversely, if $f'_+$ is left-continuous at $a$ (recall that it is always right-continuous), given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $0<a-b<\delta$ we have 
$$\tag4
0\leq f'_+(a)-f'_+(b)<\varepsilon. 
$$
Then
$$
0\leq f'_+(a)-f'_-(a)<\varepsilon+f'_+(b)-f'_-(a)\leq\varepsilon+\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'_-(a)\leq\varepsilon.
$$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $f'_+(a)=f'_-(a)$.

---

*Note:* for the second to last inequality we have, since $b<a$, 
$$
f'_+(b)\leq \frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}. 
$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71324/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-argerami-spivak-chapter-11-appendix-problem-10b).